# Error When Sending PassThrough Stream in Response with NodeJS Express Server

Tags: node.js, express, nodejs-stream

I'm trying to pass a NodeJS Stream API `PassThrough` object as the response to a http request. I'm running an Express server and am doing something similar to the following:

```
const { PassThrough } = require('stream')

const createPassThrough = () => {
  return PassThrough()
}

app.get('/stream', (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
  })
  res.write(createPassThrough())
})
```

However, when I try to do this, Express throws the following error:

```
The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of PassThrough
```

Is there anyway to do this with Express or am I going to need to use a different framework? I've read that `Hapi.js` is able to return a `PassThrough` object.

Answer (score 3):

The stream write() operations is intended to write a chunk of data rather than a reference to a readable source.

It seems that `passThrough.pipe(res)` might be what the OP indended to achieve. This will propagate all data written to the passthrough into the Express response.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! I'll see how I might be able to refactor my code to pass `res` back to the function that was originally passing the `PassThrough`. I've also managed to get it working great with `Hapi.js`, but I would like to use Express instead just because it's more familiar to me.